# Retrieve SharePoint Online File Directory

Tags: file, sharepoint, structure

I have a web application that needs to dynamically load a document library from SharePoint Online and I can't find a way to do that. I've tried looking into the Microsoft.SharePoint library and I thought that was the direction I needed to go, but I can't get that .dll to work in my Project. Does anyone else have a solution? I can't seem to find anyone else having this problem and its getting very frustrating.

Is there a NuGet package I'm missing or a different API that needs to be used?

If someone could point me in the right direction, that would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft.SharePoint only works on a SharePoint Web Front End.  Use Microsoft.SharePoint.Client, also known as CSOM, to connect remotely.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798388.aspx